# Calling findOne on a Schema with multiple uniques but only using one field in findOne's query will return not-found?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm practicing by following a React, MUI, Nodejs, CRUD project. Currently am able to get the register new user feature working but stuck on the next part where user logs in with the newly registered credentials.

So the data I'm trying to query is:

Schema - User

| userName (unique, required) | password (required) | email (unique,required) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dog123 | someLongSaltedHash | dog123@gmail.com |

Request JSON
{
userName : "dog123",
password : 'somePasswordPreHash',
}

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 50,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 8,
            max: 50,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 5,
            max: 50,
            unique: true,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

I have a model with multiple fields that have unique:true (the email and userName). When I run a controller that calls findOne({ userName: username }) and email is not provided, it always says not-found.

```
export const login = async(request, response) => {
    try {
        // Deconstruct user data from request body
        const {
            userName,
            password,
        } = request.body;

        // Query one User with matching userName
        **const queriedUser = await User.findOne({
            userName: userName,
        })**

        // If no User matched the userName, return not-found
        if (!queriedUser) {
            return response.status(400).json({
                msg: "Credentials not found, please double-check and retry later.",**  // this gets returned**
            })
        }
        // Some other code handling the passwords
        
        // Report success, and return token
        response.status(200).json({
            token: token,
            user: queriedUser,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).json({msg: error.message});** // no error thrown**
    }
}
```

The documentation for mongoose on constraints didn't really talk about what if there's multiple 'uniques' and one was not provided.

Grateful for any insight into this before I go back and refactor the model, maybe removing one of the uniques.

I tried looking up docs on how unique works but there's little info on how findOne handles being passed only data for one of the uniques.

I have verified that the User table does indeed have one item in it, and the usernames do match. The key is also correct "userName".

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(request.body)` to see if `userName` actually has 'dog123' in there? Having multiple unique values should have absolutely no effect on the `Model.findOne()` method. If you pass in the correct `key:value` pair to the function and the document exists like you said then it will 100% find the document for you.